# Why $\ker(j) \cap \text{im}(k) = k(k^{-1}(\ker j))$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I have been reading the first part of the proof that the derived couple is an exact couple below:

> [image]

But I do not understand why $\ker(j) \cap \text{im}(k) = k(k^{-1}(\ker (j))),$ could someone explain this to me please?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Note that there are no special properties of $j$ or $k$ being used here, this is a straightforward verification that the two sets are equal.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I am reading the book by myself and I got stuck in understanding this part ....... I did not get your sentence " this is a straightforward verification that the two sets are equal" ..... I am just asking about a specific step in my question.

Comment: Have you been able to show $ker(j) \cap im(k) \subseteq k(k^{-1}(ker j))$ or $ker(j) \cap im(k) \supseteq k(k^{-1}(ker j))$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Michael Albanese says in the comments, this is just unwinding basic definitions about functions. It has nothing to do with spectral sequences. $\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{\mathrm{im}}$

First, suppose $x\in \ker(j)\cap \im(k)$. Since $x\in \im(k)$, there exists $y$ such that $k(y) = x$. Since $k(y) = x\in \ker(j)$, $y\in k^{-1}(\ker(j))$. Since $x = k(y)$, $x\in k(k^{-1}(\ker(j))$. So $\ker(j)\cap \im(k)\subseteq k(k^{-1}(\ker(j))$.

Conversely, suppose $x\in k(k^{-1}(\ker(j))$. Then there is some $y\in k^{-1}(\ker(j))$ such that $k(y) = x$. Since $y\in k^{-1}(\ker(j))$, $x = k(y)\in  \ker(j)$. So $x\in \ker(j)\cap \im(k)$. Thus $k(k^{-1}(\ker(j))\subseteq \ker(j)\cap \im(k)$.

Note that we never used the function $j$ or the definition of $\ker(j)$ in the proof. The same argument shows that for any function $k\colon X\to Y$  and any $S\subseteq Y$, we have $S\cap \im(k) = k(k^{-1}(S))$.

Comment: why we are sure that $k$ has an inverse?

Comment: @Secretly When $X$ is a set; the notation $k^{-1}(X)$ refers to the *preimage* of $X$ under $k$, not to the inverse of $k$ (which may not exist).